# Get the number of variable arguments of a method in java

Tags: java, variadic-functions, string.format

Beware of potentially idiotic question below:

I have a method that uses the String.format() method to format some text. Currently, it receives two parameters, so I have two "%s" parameters to create whatever text I want to.

But someone might want to use 3 parameters, or 4, or 100, with my method. How can I get the length of the passed parameters to the String.format() method as varargs, so that, in case there are 3 parameters passed to it, there will be 3 "%s" instead of the current 2 of these; or 4, or 100.

How can you obtain the number of parameters passed to the String.format() method such that the text in it automatically adds the "%s" as needed? Because the arguments are passed as just regular arguments, not as arrays or anything like that. How can you obtain the length of the argument array?

PS. This is important - I'm not talking about obtaining the (String... arguments) - there's no such thing - when someone calls your method, it uses actual parameters, the "String... arguments" is not available to grab and obtain its length.

I realize this is a badly formulated question because I don't have the code in front of me to explain further, but this has been obsessing me for quite some time - how do you obtain the number of arguments passed to a method?

For something like this:

```
String.format(SomeObject.SomeString, param1, param2,...,param 100)
```

EDIT: The `SomeObject.SomeString` is declared like this:

`String SomeString = "Blah blah %s blah blah blah %s";`

So it has two arguments that are being hardcoded in it.

When someone uses it, how do you customize `SomeObject.SomeString` so that it "knows" how many parameters have been passed to the String.format() method (so that SomeObject.SomeString knows how many %s to add dynamically)?

Comment: How is it useful to be able to know the number of params passed to `String.format`? If you've not got the right number of params for your format string, you'll get `MissingFormatArgumentException`; if you've got too many, you won't see the extra ones there anyway. The only thing you can do is to pass `args.length` as an explicit parameter to the `String.format` call.

Answer (score 9):

> Because the arguments are passed as just regular arguments, not as arrays.

No, the values are passed as an array, therefore you could write

```
public String myVarags(String... args) {
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0;i < args.length; i++)
        s += "%s ";
    return String.format(s, args);
}
```

It will generate a `String` with a `%s` for every argument and then format the String with the given values. It will also be a very stupid and useless method.

The varargs notation is just syntactic sugar, it's an array at runtime.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to say it doesn't happen.

When someone uses that, it is simply saying `String.format(SomeObject.SomeString, param1)` or it could say `String.format(SomeObject.SomeString, param1, param2)`, an actual array is never available so that you can get its length - there are only regular parameters.

How do you reach to the method's number of parameters, what's the "name" of the array that holds these parameters? Remember, we are only using the method, not declaring it or anything else.

Comment: I am not really sure how this answers the question at all. He specially said "PS. This is important - I'm not talking about obtaining the (String... arguments) - there's no such thing - when someone calls your method, it uses actual parameters". He wants to modify `SomeObject.SomeString` based on the other arguments passed to `String.format`.

Comment: That's exactly right. I want to obtain the number of arguments passed to the String.format() method such as to modify the SomeObject.SomeString, and make it adjust to the number of parameters passed to the String.format() method.

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu What for? That doesn't sound at all like a normal way to use `String.format()`.

Comment: Well, so that, depending on the number of parameters passed to the `String.format()` method, the `SomeObject.SomeString` adjusts automatically and adds the necessary "%s" to display all the parameters arbitrarily.

By the way, this isn't my project, a colleague of mine showed this to me, and I've been thinking if what he's trying to do is possible at all.

What obsesses me is - how can you obtain the number of parameters that a called method has. The `String... args` and `args.length` that you mention would work, but I don't have access to the actual arguments array.

Comment: @Adam Through 20 years of Java experience and a long time on SO, why do you ask?

Comment: Because you have no idea of the problem he is trying to solve. What if he is trying to write a program that sings "99 bottles of beer on the wall". This would be perfectly appropriate.

Comment: @Adam No, no it wouldn't. However this looks like a classic XY problem. I can only imagine what he's really trying to do, and how on earth did he think that this would be a good solution for it.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think it's simply impossible. Since the `SomeObjectSomeString` is a parameter in the `String.format()` itself, then there's no way for it to "know" how many parameters will be passed after it.

At least, I don't think so. Although the code does indeed work. The way it's written now, it has two `%s` and takes the first parameter for the first `%s` and the second parameter for the 2nd `%s`, and everything is well and dandy. The problem is if you modify the number of parameters, and since they're varargs, they are variable.

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu No, the way is written now is the format string will have the same amount of `%s` as was passed in as varargs. It definitely doesn't have **two** `%s`s.

Comment: I meant, the way it's written now in the actual code. It's hardcoded to 2 "%s", and that's it.

My colleague wanted to make it adaptable to however many parameters it gets, but there's no way of knowing how many someone passes into it (no, there is no array that can be accessible, someone (some automatic process) will call with actual parameters, and remember - the SomeObject.SomeString that has the text is one of the parameters, so... I guess this is impossible. I personally can't think of a way to make it work.

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu Maybe your design is wrong. I can't see a real life situation where this would be necessary, or where it would be the correct solution if it were possible.

Comment: There's a high chance that you're right, and that the person that wrote the actual code simply didn't design it well, or just didn't foresee the possibility that a different number of parameters will ever be needed.

What I'm actually trying to understand is if there's a simple way of obtaining the number of parameters that a method has.

If you have a method with three parameters, is there any way you can get the number of that method's parameters programatically? I know this is stupid, you can just look at their number and that's it, but is there a way to do it programatically?

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu Yes, but as I explained, a varargs argument is counted as a single parameter. You can't get the amount of parameters used for a *single method call*. You can only get the parameters that have been defined for the method. However I really think there's a proper way to fix your problem, but you just haven't managed to explain it well enough. Even with generated code, there's no reason to try to hack `String.format()`.

Comment: Well, it's something like this:

`String stringToBeCreated = String.format(SomeObject.SomeString, param1, param2);`

`SomeObject.SomeString` is hardcoded to something like this:

`String SomeString = "Blah blah %s blah blah blah %s";`

So, if you use two arguments for it, it works, because it has two %s. What we want is for `SomeString` to automatically adjust itself to however many parameters are being passed in the `String.format()` method.

However, there's no way to "reach" the array of parameters from the `String.format()` method in `SomeObject`.

I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134560/discussion-between-kayaman-and-robert-ruxandrescu).

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu See chat discussion.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to access the number of parameters that are being passed into a different method that takes a vararg as a parameter (the `String.format()` method).

It is not possible to know how many arguments are passed into a method if you can not change the code inside the method. And the `String` parameter would certainly have no idea how many parameters were passed in. It is an entirely separate object.

The only thing you can do is create a wrapper method. You can take the same varargs and then pass them along to the `String.format()` method making whatever changes you want to do.

Then whatever code is calling `String.format()` would instead need to call your wrapper method.

Example:

```
public String StringFormatWrapper(String...args) {
    //perform actions on the args
    if (args.length > 1) 
        args[1] = "Hello World";

    //call the String.format() method
    return String.format(args)
}
```

If you don't have access to what is calling `String.format()` then what you want to do is impossible.

Comment: My hunch is sliding towards the "it's impossible" side of things.

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu I'm still on the "you don't have a clue what you're doing" side. If only you could explain yourself clearly.

Comment: That's just because I don't have the code before me. I saw it for a little time and I'm just reproducing here whatever I can remember.

The main idea is that there's a String declared and it uses the `String.format()` method to be created, for which the first argument is that SomeObject.SomeString that's hardcoded for 2 parameters, and then the varargs for the rest of the parameters in the `String.format()` method.

So the final String will be the result of the hardcoded String as the first parameter and all the other following parameters that the hardcoded string uses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking is possible because your `SomeObject.SomeString` is just an argument, it doesn't know anything about the other arguments. What you could do is turn your arguments into an array of varargs and create a method on `SomeObject` to generate the correct string:

```
String[] args = ...
String.format(SomeObject.createSomeString(args.length), args);
```

Comment: Yeah it's a really weird situation, I'm also wondering if it's possible at all. My question is - is there any way to "count" the number of arguments that someone passed to a method? Like, say you have method A(param1, param2, param3) - is there any way in Java to obtain the information that this method has three parameters called? Is the number of parameters that a method has being "stored" anywhere?

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu yes, you can call `.length` on the variadic argument. It's just an array.

Comment: Yeah but what's the name of that array? For the method A(param1, param2, param3), what is the name of the parameter array that contains the parameters?

Comment: Yes all of that is stored on the `Method` object. You can get a handle to a `Method` object several ways, check the reflection docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html. You can do `Method m = ... ; m.getParameterTypes().length();`

Comment: Of course if the method takes a varargs param, it will count as one parameter, since it's an array. Going through reflection won't give you any more information than you already know.

Comment: This is getting really confusing... How do you actually create the Method object and make it "represent" the method you're trying to obtain the information about, such that you can then call `m.getParameterCount()`, for example?

Also, it doesn't seem to have any practical constructor.

Answer (score -2):

I have thought about it a bit more and I have come up with a solution for this, and the solution is a very simple one. In fact, I wrote it in 5 minutes.

Here's how it goes:

MAIN CLASS:

```
public class Main {

    SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();
        main.formatString("a","b","c","D","efesfs");

    }

    public void formatString(String...varargs){
        String formattedString = String.format(someObject.returnFormattedString(varargs.length), varargs);
        System.out.println(formattedString);
    }
}
```

SOMEOBJECT CLASS:

```
public class SomeObject {

    public String someString = "Blah blah blah";

    public String returnFormattedString(int numberOfArguments){
        for (int i = 0; i<numberOfArguments; i++){
            someString += "%s";
        }

        return someString;
    }
}
```

In other words, I'm wrapping all that stuff inside a method that will have access to how many parameters are passed as arguments, and I will pass the number of them (as varargs.length) to the method inside the SomeObject class that will take the length as an int variable and using a for loop, will add as many "%s" as needed.

It works like a charm.

I know some people criticized me that this is not "right", "it's not the right question to ask" and so on, but at least it has a simple solution, like I thought it should have, and it's not "impossible", you don't need to break down bytecode at runtime or anything crazy.

Comment: "Your" solution is exactly what was suggested to you in literally every other answer here.

Comment: Yes and no. Technically, you are right, and it's the same solution that I got. But my original question was if I could determine the number of arguments from the actual call of the method, without writing a new one and calling that one, like you and I did.

So, yeah.